# Trying to install PHPCR-ODM

Tags: symfony

Im getting this error:

```
>  Problem 1
> - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.4.x-dev].
> - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev requires jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal dev-master -> no matching package
> found.   Potential causes:
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see
> <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion>
> for more details.
```

with this configuration:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
         "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.0.*",
                        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.0.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help?
when trying to install using composer

Im just following these [instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/installing_configuring_doctrine_phpcr_odm.html).

Since the package is here: https://github.com/jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal Could you tell why am I getting that error? I would be greatful if you tell me *reason*, not only "change this or that".

**EDIT**: after the answer of Flask, I have now this line:

```
"jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "dev-master@dev",
```

but now I get this error message:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install phpcr/phpcr-utils 1.0-beta5
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0-beta1, 1.0-beta2, 1.0-beta3, 1.0-beta4, 1.0-beta5, 1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.1 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0-beta1, 1.0-beta2, 1.0-beta3, 1.0-beta4, 1.0-beta5, 1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.x-dev requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0-beta1, 1.0-beta2, 1.0-beta3, 1.0-beta4, 1.0-beta5, 1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-RC1 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-RC2 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-RC3 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-RC4 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-RC5 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-alpha1 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-beta6 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-alpha2 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-beta6 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-beta1 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-beta6 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-beta2 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-beta6 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-beta3 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-beta6 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-beta4 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-beta6 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.0-beta5 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.0.0-beta6 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-beta10, 1.0.0-beta11, 1.0.0-beta12, 1.0.0-beta13, 1.0.0-beta14, 1.0.0-beta6, 1.0.0-beta7, 1.0.0-beta8, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0-beta1].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0-beta2].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0-beta3].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0-beta4].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC1].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta10].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta11].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta12].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta13].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta14].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta6].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta7].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta8].
    - Can only install one of: phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.0.0-beta9].
    - jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal dev-master requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ~1.1.0 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.1.0-RC1, 1.1.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install phpcr/phpcr-utils 1.1.x-dev|install phpcr/phpcr-utils 1.0-beta5
    - Installation request for doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/phpcr-odm[1.0.0, 1.0.0-RC1, 1.0.0-RC2, 1.0.0-RC3, 1.0.0-RC4, 1.0.0-RC5, 1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.0-alpha2, 1.0.0-beta1, 1.0.0-beta2, 1.0.0-beta3, 1.0.0-beta4, 1.0.0-beta5, 1.0.1, 1.0.x-dev].
```

Comment: Still no answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add `jackalope` to your composer json as dev

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.0.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "dev-master@dev",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.0.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, **First question**: how to know this kind of things to not always ask in Stackoverflow about it? **Second question**: I have a new error I have addded in my question.

Comment: if you want to use jackalope-doctrine-dbal at dev-master you also have to use `phpcr/phpcr-utils` at version 1.1.0 or greater.
try to set `"phpcr/phpcr-utils": "~1.1.0"` maybe there is no release of it tagged stable, than you have to use `"phpcr/phpcr-utils": "~1.1.0@dev"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the dependencies this way:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "dev-master",
        "phpcr/phpcr-utils": "~1.1.0",
        "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "*"
```

First update the doctrine/orm package to 2.3.*

Then, as Flask recommended, include the phpcr-utils package **BEFORE** the phpcr-odm package

Answer (score 0):

Solution: taken from https://github.com/symfony-cmf/MenuBundle/issues/86

since it is the dependencies and versions issue i must give you a combination that works! And you can change or upgrade it from there.

Symfony 2.*

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "symfony-cmf/menu-bundle": "1.0.*@beta",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.0.*@beta",
    "phpcr/phpcr": "2.1.*@beta",
    "phpcr/phpcr-utils": "1.0.*@beta",
    "phpcr/phpcr-implementation": "2.1.*@beta",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.0.*@beta",
    "doctrine/common": "2.4.*@dev",
    "symfony-cmf/core-bundle": "1.0.*@beta",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.0.*@beta"
},
```

This is my entire composer.json just in case other info needed.

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php": "dev-master",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
    "seegno/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/filesystem": "^2.8",
    "liip/search-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony-cmf/menu-bundle": "1.0.*@beta",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "*",
    "phpcr/phpcr": "2.1.*@beta",
    "phpcr/phpcr-utils": "1.0.*@beta",
    "phpcr/phpcr-implementation": "*",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.0.*@beta",
    "doctrine/common": "2.4.*@dev",
    "symfony-cmf/core-bundle": "1.0.*@beta",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.0.*@beta"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
    }
}}
```

Dont forget to install search-bundle itself with command: (composer require symfony-cmf/search-bundle). Please mark as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Here is the composer.json of stable versions that may work but i have not tested: https://github.com/doctrine/phpcr-odm/blob/master/composer.json